# In Applescript, how do I get a line number or stack trace on error?

Tags: applescript, error

I'm writing some fairly complex Applescripts, but when something goes wrong - Apple event timed out - or similar, I can't tell precisely where it failed.

At the moment, I'm wrapping all handlers with try blocks, with an on error that re-raises the error, with a reference to the handler name and the value of a variable that I set at various points through the handler so I can isolate the error to somewhere between two points.

** Is there a way to get Applescript to say 'Apple event timed out at line 15 in await(), at line 60 in connectRemoteUser(), at line 90 in autostartTestUsers()' *without having to code it all directly*?

I can't rely on the script editor's location highlighting because the errors happen intermittently when the script is out in production.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I share your frustration.

Comment: @rubik'ssphere Sadly, no. Happily, we've moved away from AppleScript (which I was using to start multiple desktops on the same machine, to run multiple simulators) because Facebook's fbsimctl made things much easier. If I never have to write another Applescript abomination, I'll be a happy bunny.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly but it works...

```
try
    set marker to 1
    -- do stuff
    set marker to 2
    -- do stuff
    set marker to 3
    1 / 0
    set marker to 4
on error errMsg number errNum
    tell application "SystemUIServer"
        display alert (marker & space & errMsg & return & return & "Error number " & errNum as text) buttons "Cancel" cancel button "Cancel"
    end tell
end try
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I said I didn't want to be doing in the question: I'm already catching and re-raising errors for all handlers, and only displaying the dialogue for the topmost.